# Bluetooth LE device stopped connecting in Windows 10 v1709

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, wdk

I've created a WDK library for interacting with a Bluetooth LE device (closly following the example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/bad452cb-4fc2-4a86-9b60-070b43577cc9/is-there-a-simple-example-desktop-programming-c-for-bluetooth-low-energy-devices?forum=wdk)). The library worked well on a previous version of Windows - I was able to connect to my device, write characteristics and get asynchronous notifications. Once I updated to Windows to version 1709 (build 16299.98), the library stopped working:

- pair the device via Settings-->Devices-->Bluetooth
- the BLE device blinks a led as an indication of Advertising
- Run my application which uses aforesaid library
- Once the application opens the paired device's handle (using `hDevice = CreateFile(pInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);`), the device blinks spasmodically, indicating that it connects and disconnects very fast.
- Sometimes, after several long seconds, the device has solid light, indicating it is connected (the status in Windows Settings is also 'Connected')
- Any access to the device from my code (e.g. by calling `BluetoothGATTSetDescriptorValue()` to enable BLE notification), fails with a timeout (`ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT`))

For some reason, first-time pairing with the device does not exhibit these symptoms.

Any ideas?

If its relevant, my local Bluetooth device is Qualcom Atheros USB module  (VID_0489&PID_E076&REV_0001).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Windows 10, resolved in [KB4054517](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4054517/windows-10-update-kb4054517)