# Detecting BLE device in range on Win32

Tags: winapi, bluetooth-lowenergy

If a device has an HID over GATT service, Windows will automatically connect to it. So, it clearly is paying attention to when the device is in range.

For a non-HID device, Win32 only connects to the BLE device when I make a request to it, such as setting a characteristic or registering for a notification. How can I detect when the device can be connected to successfully (is in range)? I'm tempted to just run a loop attempting to connect, but surely that cannot be the best solution.

Comment: BluetoothLeAdvertisementWatcher (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher)

Comment: I guess you have to perform a Bluetooth LE scan.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use Win32/WinAPI (as opposed [BluetoothLeAdvertisementWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher), which is a UWP class), you can use methods from [bluetoothapis.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bluetoothapis/).

You basically need to create a message-pumping window, and handle incoming `WM_DEVICECHANGE` event. Something like this:

```
INT_PTR BleListener::EventLoopHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT result = 1;   
    DEBUG_PRINT(TEXT("Message: 0x%04x\n"), message);

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
        {
            DEV_BROADCAST_HDR* hdr;
            DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE* bhandle;
            if (wParam == DBT_CUSTOMEVENT)
            {
                hdr = (DEV_BROADCAST_HDR*)lParam;

                if (hdr->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE)
                {
                    bhandle = (DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE*)lParam;
                    if (bhandle->dbch_eventguid == GUID_BLUETOOTH_RADIO_IN_RANGE)
                    {
                        BTH_DEVICE_INFO* info = (BTH_DEVICE_INFO*)bhandle->dbch_data;
                        DEBUG_PRINT(TEXT("GUID_BLUETOOTH_RADIO_IN_RANGE. Address = 0x%llx\n"), info->address);
                    }
                }
                else if (bhandle->dbch_eventguid == GUID_BLUETOOTH_HCI_EVENT)
                {
                    ...
                }
            };
        break;        

        ...
    }
}
```

You might also wanna take a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/bad452cb-4fc2-4a86-9b60-070b43577cc9/is-there-a-simple-example-desktop-programming-c-for-bluetooth-low-energy-devices?forum=wdk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777899/bluetooth-le-device-stopped-connecting-in-windows-10-v1709) for some gotchas.

Comment: These events only raise on connection, not while the device is unconnected. Do I need to do anything to get them to raise consistently?

Comment: @Zer From my experience with Win32 API on Windows 10, the whole 'connection/disconnection' thing is handled (rather poorly IMO) by Windows. It can literally disconnect you without warning, and reconnect you if you attempt to e.g. read a characteristic on the remote device. The closest I managed to get to a BLE scan is handling `GUID_BLUETOOTH_RADIO_IN_RANGE`, which worked most of the time.